# Dapper and In Condition

Tags: dapper, sqlexception

Using Dapper, the following throws `Incorrect syntax near ','`.

```
const string sql = 
    "select * from ZipToZipDistance z where z.NoRouteFound = 0" +
    " and z.OriginZip in (@zips) or z.DestZip in (@zips)";
var zipStrings = zips.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
var result = connection.Query<ZipToZipDistance>(sql, 
    new { zips = zipStrings });
```

Hmm, the SQL has no commas.  It must have something to do with the parameter.  `OriginZip` and `DestZip` are `varchar(10)`.  `zips` is `IEnumerable<int>`.  I tried using `zips` as the parameter without the converting to strings.  Same error.

Seems very straightforward.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the brackets from @zips

Comment: Had same problem just now and I just removed the brackets/parentheses around @zips. Just iike jaxxbo says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try:

```
const string sql = 
    "select * from ZipToZipDistance z where z.NoRouteFound = 0" +
    " and z.OriginZip in @zips or z.DestZip in @zips";
var zipStrings = zips.Select(x => x.ToString());
var result = connection.Query<ZipToZipDistance>(sql, 
    new { zips = zipStrings });
```

Comment: Sam the problem I'm running into is that I can only pass 2100 items in the IN clause which seems to be a dapper limitation because when I construct the query using the string concatenation it works just fine. Here is what I mean:

Working Code:
     var query = @"SELECT * FROM QuestionTags WHERE QuestionID IN (" + idsCsvString + ")";
     var results = conn.Query<QuestionTag>(query).ToList();

Comment: When I do it the way you're suggesting I get the following error:

The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100